# Property [nombre] does not exist on this collection instance. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy realizando un proyecto en PHP con Laravel 5.6 y lo que deseo es lo siguiente: tengo una tabla llamada "ordenes"(id, ciudad, empresa, entre otros campos), otra llamada "examenes_ordenes"(id, orden_id) y otra llamada "examenes"(id, nombre).
quiero que me traiga los exámenes correspondientes a mi orden pero me arroja el siguiente error.

> Property [nombre] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: D:\SOA\soa\resources\views\ordenes\show_fields.blade.php)

OrdenController.php

```
    public function show($id)

{
    $ordenes = Orden::where('id',$id)->with('orden_examen')->get();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('ordenes.show_fields', compact('ordenes'));
    return $pdf->stream('ordenes'); }
```

Modelo Orden.php

```
    public function orden_examen(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Examen_Orden','orden_id','id');
}
```

show_fields.blade.php

```
<table class="table" id="orden-tabla">

    <tr>
        <th>Lista de exámenes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>    
          <p>  
               @foreach ($ordenes as $object)
                  {{ $object->orden_examen->nombre }}
               @endforeach
          </p>
    </tr>
```

Comment: 1. ¿Hay más de una orden? lo pregunto porque usas get() y no first() con un id. 2. ¿Qué arroja un dump de $object->orden_examen?

Comment: En la pregunta expresa que tiene "examenes_ordenes" pero en el codigo utiliza "orden_examen". No vendrá por ahí el problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> El problema está en que tu modelo `Orden` tiene una relación con el
>   modelo `Examen_Orden` de uno a muchos, entonces NO puedes acceder a la
>   relación de esta forma `$object->orden_examen->nombre`, lo que
>   tendrías que hacer sería recorrer la relación de la siguiente forma:
>
> ```
> @foreach ($ordenes as $object)
>    @foreach($object->orden_examen as $orden_examen)
>       {{ $orden_examen->nombre }}
>    @endforeach
> @endforeach
> ```
>
> Por otro lado, como tu relación es de uno a muchos y por lo tanto te
>   devuelve una colección, puedes acceder a los elementos de esa
>   colección mediante el índice, por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> @foreach ($ordenes as $object)
>    {{ $object->orden_examen[0]->nombre }}
> @endforeach
> ```

Ya me funciona y lo hice de la siguiente manera:

en mi archivo show_files.blade

```
          @foreach ($ordenes as $object)
             @foreach($object->orden_examen as $orden_examen)
             <br>
                {{ $orden_examen->examen_paciente->nombre }}
             @endforeach
          @endforeach
```

en mi modelo Orden

```
public function orden_examen(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Examen_Orden','orden_id','id');
}
```

y en mi modelo Examen_Orden

```
 public function examen_paciente(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Examen','id','examen_id');
}
```

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas y por tu ayuda **Aarón Gutiérrez**

Comment: Ya no me arroja error pero ahora me aparece en blanco... resulta que la relación "orden_examen" que tengo en mi Modelo "Orden" me funciona con otra vista a la perfección.  lo que necesito es, por ejemplo,  que me busque en mi tabla "examenes_ordenes", los registros que coincidan con mi "id_orden" porque este campo es el mismo "id" de mi tabla Ordenes, no se si esa relación iría en mi Modelo "Examen_Orden" y de que manera lo haría??

muchas gracias.

Comment: Las relaciones en los modelos de Laravel deberían de ir siempre en ambos lados, tu ya cuentas con la relación `orden_examen` en el modelo `Orden`, peor para traer los datos de manera inversa tendrías que agregar la relación de la siguiente forma:

`public function orden(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Orden','orden_id','id');
}`